# An estimate for dividing n^2 by each of the primes up to and including n, and then summing the results

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that the asymptotic for the sum of all the primes up to n is $n^2/2\log n$. But I'm trying to find the formula (an estimate) for when $n^2$ is divided by each of the primes up to $n$, in turn -- and then summing the results.

Comment: Computationally it seems to have order of magnitude $n^2/\log n$ as well, although it's not quite clear whether it's asymptotic to a constant time that. The sum you want is essentially $\sum_{p\le\sqrt x} p\big\{ \frac xp \big\}$, where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part function. There's a somewhat similar result in Proposition 3 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0232v3.pdf; perhaps similar methods would help here.

Comment: The uniqueness of prime factorization implies that every prime factor of $n^k$ is a prime factor of $n$.

Comment: It seems from the comments that everybody interprets the meaning of the question in a different way, so maybe you should clarify it. My reading is that you are asking for $\sum_{p\le n}\frac{n^2}p$, which is well known to be asymptotic to $n^2\log\log n$.